# Rotate UIButton TitleLabel without UIButton Frame (Swift)

Tags: xcode, swift, uibutton, transform

I would like to rotate the title label of a UIButton (so the text is vertical/90 degrees without rotating the button.

```
myButton.titleLabel?.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2))
```

Comment: and...? so...? do you have an issue, maybe?

Comment: Yes. Sorry. When it rotates it seems to be clipped and just display "..."

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell, you don't give enough information!

Maybe try resizing the button to fit the content after the rotation?

myButton.sizeToFit()